# configure two LAN cards on a local server and access a locally hosted web app on LAN and on internet

Tags: networking, server, internet, nginx, nodejs

I have a ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine running as local server (I have a web app running on it).
I have two questions as below.

1] How to configure two LAN cards on the above server ?

2] After configuring two LAN cards

- I want my office team to be able to access the web app on LAN (locally)     on say eth0 (typing 192.168.0.11 in browser should open the web app).
- I want to make the web app accessible on internet using say eth1 which is connected to a router having a static ip address.

**The web app is a node js application running behind ngnix**

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The eth0 need to be configured as follows

```
netsh interface ip set address name=192.168.0.11 source=192.168.0.1
```

and assign the eth1 as follows

```
netsh interface ip set address name=”StaticIP” source=dhcp
```

Now restart the network

```
service networking restart
```

Your local application will be available to the local network and it can be tested as follows

```
curl 192.168.0.11/application-path
```

Cheers and all the best